# Running Java on cmd

Tags: java, cmd

Why on writing java -version on cmd it shows 3 error although i have installed Java Jdk and jre installed in my system?

errors are as follow:

```
oppening register key 'software\JavaSoft\JRE'
could not find java.dll
Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

it shows error:
[image: it shows error]

Comment: Perhaps check your systems PATH environment variable

Comment: yes, I check it is correct.

Comment: in what directory do you have installed your jre?

Comment: in C in directory

Comment: I installed my java in C directory and it does not work when I run a java file through cmd but when I run it through eclipse it runs correctly

Comment: @AdhikanshMittal that is, because eclipse comes with its own jdk

Comment: @Lino oh thank you. I don't know about it.but what about cmd

Comment: @AdhikanshMittal have a look at the duplicate link

Answer (score 0):

Go to: Advanced system settings -> Environment variables 
in the  system variables section add variable name : JAVA_HOME , and value the path of your jdk . then try again .also add jre path in the path variables .

Comment: I try it, But it does not work

Comment: make sure about the jre being installed. try an other version , hope it works